# How can I replace non-printable Unicode characters in Java?

Tags: java, string, unicode

The following will replace ASCII control characters (shorthand for `[\x00-\x1F\x7F]`):

```
my_string.replaceAll("\\p{Cntrl}", "?");
```

The following will replace all ASCII non-printable characters (shorthand for `[\p{Graph}\x20]`), including accented characters:

```
my_string.replaceAll("[^\\p{Print}]", "?");
```

However, neither works for Unicode strings. Does anyone has a good way to remove non-printable characters from a unicode string?

Comment: Just as an addendum: the list of Unicode General Categories can be found in [UAX #44](http://unicode.org/reports/tr44/#GC_Values_Table)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fastest way to strip all non-printable characters from a Java String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7161534/fastest-way-to-strip-all-non-printable-characters-from-a-java-string)

Comment: @Stewart: hi, have you looked at the question/answers besides the title?!?

Comment: @Stewart: that other question covers only the ascii subset of non-printable characters!!!

Answer (score 169, accepted):

```
my_string.replaceAll("\\p{C}", "?");
```

See more about [Unicode regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html). `java.util.regexPattern`/`String.replaceAll` supports them.

Comment: In java 1.6 at least, there is no support for them. http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html ...I also tried your line out, and besides of missing a backslash, it plainly simply doesn't work.

Comment: This works: `char c = 0xFFFA;
    String.valueOf(c).replaceAll("\\p{C}", "?");` also in the javadoc for pattern look in the **Unicode support** section, says it supports the categories

Comment: You are right! I apologize. I didn't noticed it because I had to add the Zl Zp categories since those were mostly the source of issues. It works perfectly. Could you please make a mini edit to your post so I can vote it up again?

Comment: There are also invisible whitespace characters (like 0x0200B), which are part of \p{Zs} group. Unfortunately, this one includes also normal whitespaces. For those who are trying to filter an input string that shouldn't contain any spaces, the string `s.replaceAll("[\\p{C}\\p{Z}]", "")` will do the charm

Comment: This is what I was looking for, I was trying `replaceAll("[^\\u0000-\\uFFFF]", "")` but had no success

Comment: Thank you for you answer. We are using this filter, but then emoji character got stripped. How do you strip non-printable char without touching emoji?

Comment: Why are you replacing them with "?"

Comment: Attention: this solution presented here (with 150 upvotes) also removes line breaks, which you might don't want to be replaced.

Answer (score 71):

Op De Cirkel is mostly right.  His suggestion will work in most cases:

> ```
> myString.replaceAll("\\p{C}", "?");
> ```

But if `myString` might contain non-BMP codepoints then it's more complicated.  `\p{C}` contains the surrogate codepoints of `\p{Cs}`.  The replacement method above will corrupt non-BMP codepoints by sometimes replacing only half of the surrogate pair.  It's possible this is a Java bug rather than intended behavior.

Using the other constituent categories is an option:

```
myString.replaceAll("[\\p{Cc}\\p{Cf}\\p{Co}\\p{Cn}]", "?");
```

However, solitary surrogate characters not part of a pair (each surrogate character has an assigned codepoint) will not be removed.  A non-regex approach is the only way I know to properly handle `\p{C}`:

```
StringBuilder newString = new StringBuilder(myString.length());
for (int offset = 0; offset < myString.length();)
{
    int codePoint = myString.codePointAt(offset);
    offset += Character.charCount(codePoint);

    // Replace invisible control characters and unused code points
    switch (Character.getType(codePoint))
    {
        case Character.CONTROL:     // \p{Cc}
        case Character.FORMAT:      // \p{Cf}
        case Character.PRIVATE_USE: // \p{Co}
        case Character.SURROGATE:   // \p{Cs}
        case Character.UNASSIGNED:  // \p{Cn}
            newString.append('?');
            break;
        default:
            newString.append(Character.toChars(codePoint));
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

methods below for your goal

```
public static String removeNonAscii(String str)
{
    return str.replaceAll("[^\\x00-\\x7F]", "");
}

public static String removeNonPrintable(String str) // All Control Char
{
    return str.replaceAll("[\\p{C}]", "");
}

public static String removeSomeControlChar(String str) // Some Control Char
{
    return str.replaceAll("[\\p{Cntrl}\\p{Cc}\\p{Cf}\\p{Co}\\p{Cn}]", "");
}

public static String removeFullControlChar(String str)
{
    return removeNonPrintable(str).replaceAll("[\\r\\n\\t]", "");
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You may be interested in the [Unicode categories](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/index.htm) ["Other, Control"](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Cc/index.htm) and *possibly* ["Other, Format"](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Cf/index.htm) (unfortunately the latter seems to contain both unprintable and printable characters).

In Java regular expressions you can check for them using `\p{Cc}` and `\p{Cf}` respectively.

Comment: Well, too bad java expressions don't have them, but at least I got the list right now... better than nothing. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have used this simple function for this:

```
private static Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[^ -~]");
private static String cleanTheText(String text) {
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
    if ( matcher.find() ) {
        text = text.replace(matcher.group(0), "");
    }
    return text;
}
```

Hope this is useful.

Comment: What does that regular expression do?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answers by **Op De Cirkel** and **noackjr**, the following is what I do for general string cleaning: 1. trimming leading or trailing whitespaces, 2. dos2unix, 3. mac2unix, 4. removing all "invisible Unicode characters" except whitespaces:

`myString.trim.replaceAll("\r\n", "\n").replaceAll("\r", "\n").replaceAll("[\\p{Cc}\\p{Cf}\\p{Co}\\p{Cn}&&[^\\s]]", "")`

Tested with Scala REPL.

Answer (score 0):

I propose it remove the non printable characters like below instead of replacing it

```
private String removeNonBMPCharacters(final String input) {
    StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    input.codePoints().forEach((i) -> {
        if (Character.isSupplementaryCodePoint(i)) {
            strBuilder.append("?");
        } else {
            strBuilder.append(Character.toChars(i));
        }
    });
    return strBuilder.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Supported multilanguage

```
public static String cleanUnprintableChars(String text, boolean multilanguage)
{
    String regex = multilanguage ? "[^\\x00-\\xFF]" : "[^\\x00-\\x7F]";
    // strips off all non-ASCII characters
    text = text.replaceAll(regex, "");

    // erases all the ASCII control characters
    text = text.replaceAll("[\\p{Cntrl}&&[^\r\n\t]]", "");

    // removes non-printable characters from Unicode
    text = text.replaceAll("\\p{C}", "");

    return text.trim();
}
```

Answer (score -4):

I have redesigned the code for phone numbers +9 (987) 124124
[Extract digits from a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4030928/extract-digits-from-a-string-in-java)

```
 public static String stripNonDigitsV2( CharSequence input ) {
    if (input == null)
        return null;
    if ( input.length() == 0 )
        return "";

    char[] result = new char[input.length()];
    int cursor = 0;
    CharBuffer buffer = CharBuffer.wrap( input );
    int i=0;
    while ( i< buffer.length()  ) { //buffer.hasRemaining()
        char chr = buffer.get(i);
        if (chr=='u'){
            i=i+5;
            chr=buffer.get(i);
        }

        if ( chr > 39 && chr < 58 )
            result[cursor++] = chr;
        i=i+1;
    }

    return new String( result, 0, cursor );
}
```