# Android String Equals and contentEquals return false, but both String Print as Same

Tags: java, android, compare, base64, equals

**Program Flow**

**Sender** - Generate encryption key as byte[] and **show** its `Base64.encodeToString` value to the user then sent that byte[] (key) to the Receiver as udp packet

**Receiver** - Receive UDP packet and get the key (byte[]), and Getting the Key from user as String (user know the string becoz I shown in Sender program) and convert received key (byte[]) to String using `Base64.encodeToString`

Here is the Problem, when I compare Both String using `equals` it return false

When I print both string in logcat

the Output is

> 12-05 15:39:32.047: V/userkey(2210): oIAfhtGnf+tBX8NBB5ONVQ==
>
> 12-05 15:39:32.047: V/reckey(2210): oIAfhtGnf+tBX8NBB5ONVQ==

here you can see both string has same character sequence

**Important**

I searched lot and coming to know about `contentEquals`, I tried this too with hope that it will solve my issue becoz its just compare the characters and sequence of both string,
But I can't get this working, its too returning false for these Strings...

I get the String from user in EditText as

```
txtDeKey.getText().toString()
```

and converting byte[] to String as (tried both)

```
Base64.encodeToString(key1, Base64.DEFAULT).toString()
Base64.encodeToString(key1, Base64.DEFAULT)
```

Comment: Inspect both strings in the debugger.  Check the lengths and look for leading/trailing nulls.

Comment: Yes, there may be some non-printable characters in it, that you can't see on standard output.

Comment: @Simon then wat is the solution for this problem..., how to trim nulls...

Comment: @UdoKlimaschewski how to trim non-printable characters

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6198986/how-can-i-replace-non-printable-unicode-characters-in-java but have a look at the bytes in your string first, the problem may be that those character(s) came into the String in the first place. Removing them is curing the symptoms, not the cause.

Comment: Thanks @UdoKlimaschewski
I solved the problem by using `Base64.encodeToString(keyDe, Base64.DEFAULT).replaceAll("\\p{C}", "?")` wherever I'm encoding byte[] to String...