# Replace all non-printable UTF-8 characters with spaces

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I need to sanitaze some user input and I need to remove all the characters can cause problems such as Null Byte or useless ones(such as \n or \t), because the inputs are or strings or html code.
At this moment I'm using this to remove the tab, break-line, etc:

```
preg_replace('/\s+/','',$_POST['id'])
```

but isn't sufficent, I have found this:

```
preg_replace( '/[^[:print:]]/',' ',$_POST['val'])
```

But I don't understand if it strips also characters that shouldn't be deleted, such as german or arabic chars or punctation or symbols

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I replace non-printable Unicode characters in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6198986/how-can-i-replace-non-printable-unicode-characters-in-java)

Comment: @M42 does `\p{C}` keep "special" chars like the german or arabic or swedish ones? Is it interpreted by PHP?

Comment: IFAIK, yes it does keep all char that is "printable".

Comment: @M42 I don't think a php question is a duplicate of a java question.  Just because somebody asked already how to achieve the same functionality in another language doesn't mean that the question is duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [PHP regex character classes](http://www.php.net/manual/de/regexp.reference.character-classes.php) `[:print:]` includes "*printing characters, including space*".

That means "*Visible characters and spaces (i.e. anything except control characters, etc.)*" (see http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html)

- ASCII characters: `[\x20-\x7E]`
- Unicode: `\P{C}`