# Java function matches is not recognizing [0-9]+ for numbers

Tags: java, regex

I'm getting a phone number from an external API call and I'm trying to detect if it is indeed a number (I don't care at this point if it's a valid phone number). For simplicity's sake, I tried:

```
String number = phone.replace("+", "").replace(" ", "").trim();
if (number.matches("[0-9]+")) {
    return true;
}
```

The string I'm getting in `number` is something like ‪331234212453 but `matches` returns false. What is weird is that when I inspect the `number` variable, copy its value and try:

```
‪"331234212453".matches("[0-9]+")
```

It still does not work. Now if I type those same numbers and use `matches` then I get it to work. Could there be some kind of encoding messing up with the string? And if so how do I fix it?

Edit: Forgot to say that I tried `number.matches("\\d+")` and it also does not work.

Comment: why not `\d` regex match?

Comment: Use `String.getBytes("UTF-8")` and examine the individual byte values to see if something unexpected is in there.

Comment: @Ricardo Unicode replacement of control characters: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6198986/how-can-i-replace-non-printable-unicode-characters-in-java

Comment: @Ricardo - could you post a few examples of failing input? also - did you consider using replaceAll() instead of replace() ?

Comment: @radai What do you mean by example? I put one in my question, `331234212453`.

Comment: @Ricardo - that means you have some control character in there. try printing out character by character and see what it is

Comment: @GregS `getBytes` returns [-30, -128, -86, 57, 51, 48, 50] for "‪9302". What does that mean?

Answer (score 2):

1st of all when you want to clear all whitespaces you usually dont want to settle for just space. this is much safer:

```
replaceAll("\\s+","")
```

as it removes any number of consecutive whitespace characters, and not just spaces.
next up, there's a digit class in java regexp syntax, so you could try

```
matches("\\d+")
```

also - notice the difference between replace() (which deals with chars) and replaceAll() (which deals in strings and patterns)

Comment: Thanks. Forgot to say that I had tried with `number.matches("\\d+")` but it also doesn't work.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth - OP did not provide specific examples of failing input, so we're left guessing

Comment: @radai What do you mean by example? I put the number I'm trying to match in my question. Here is a direct copy from one that is not working in my inspector when I try it, not sure it will matter here: `"‪9302".matches("\\d+")`. This is returning false for me there.

Comment: @radai and using `replaceAll("\\s+","")` does not help either.