# Problems decoding JSON with json-simple

Tags: java, json

I followed this tutorial on how to decode json with java: https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/DecodingExamples

In my project i get  `info_string`:

```
   {"server_ip":"http://localhost:3000/","device_id":14}
```

that i would like to decode: I tried:

```
  System.out.println(info_string);
 => {"server_ip":"http://localhost:3000/","device_id":14}
  Object obj = JSONValue.parse(info_string);
  System.out.println(obj);
 => null
  JSONArray array=(JSONArray)obj;
 => null
  System.out.println(array);
```

As you can see the `array` and `obj` variable are `null` and contain no data!
What do i wrong? Thanks

Comment: Any non-printable/invisible characters in the String you got from the server?  `String info_string = "\u0000{\"server_ip\":\"http://localhost:3000/\",\"device_id\":14}";` would demonstrate the behavior you are seeing. Otherwise it's working fine for me (until you try to cast `obj` to a `JSONArray` but that's another story).

Comment: @ZouZou what would you do to fix this problem? Trim() the string?

Comment: @ZouZou you are right `info_string.trim()` works! Could you please write an answer?

Comment: @ZouZou and hoy can i get the single values? For example `device_id` from this `obj`? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are certainly non-printable/invisible characters. I suggest you to use a [regular expression to remove them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6198986/how-can-i-replace-non-printable-unicode-characters-in-java), because if you String looks like

```
String info_string = "   {\"server_ip\":\u0000\"http://localhost:3000/\",\"device_id\":14}";
```

`trim()` will do nothing.

So try with:

```
Object obj = JSONValue.parse(info_string.replaceAll("\\p{C}", ""));
```

---

> and how can i get the single values? For example device_id from this
>   obj?

In your case, `parse` will return a `JSONObject`, so you can cast the result, and then use the `get` method to get the value associated with the corresponding key:

```
JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) JSONValue.parse(info_string);
String serverIp = (String) obj.get("server_ip"); //http://localhost:3000/    
long deviceId = (Long) obj.get("device_id"); //14
```