# How to clean a csv file from weird characters (e.g. SUB)?

Tags: java, csv, jdbc, teradata

I am uploading csv files using `jdbc` to teradata. Everything used to be fine, until recently I came across a `csv` file that had some weird characters and my code failed to upload .

I opened the `csv` file in Notepad ++ , and it look like this `SUB` . When I open it in Excel it looks like this `->->`

When I manually deleted those characters, everything went back to normal. I am curious , is there any way I could use `java` to clean a `csv` file to remove all kind of invalid characters  ?

Comment: Can you show some screenshot from Notepad++ and Excel where these characters are shown?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SUB character is an ASCII 26 (= hex 0x1A). Back when DEC-10s ruled the earth, this was called Ctrl-Z. It is used to indicate the end of a file.

If it indeed at the end of the file, and you read it in using a Java InputStream (and please have a look at [Read/convert an InputStream to a String](https://stackoverflow.com/q/309424/509840)) it will take off that terminal Ctrl-Z.

It would be quite unusual (and a problem) to have the SUB inside the CSV data, unless it were representing a binary object.

Comment: Thank you. I had a feeling it was the end of file flag because i tried to import it to BI tools like SAS etc. and it got imported until the first `SUB`

Answer (score 3):

You can try:

```
myString.replaceAll("\\p{C}", "?");
```

If you want to remove it:

```
myString.replaceAll("\\p{C}", "");
```

More here:
[How can I replace non-printable Unicode characters in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6198986/how-can-i-replace-non-printable-unicode-characters-in-java)