# Android Java - NumberFormatException while parsing "76"

Tags: java, android, zlib, numberformatexception, parseint

I'm working on an Android app using zbar to decode QR.
The structure of the QR is: "SpecificPrefix/*[Number]*".

```
String d = sym.getData(); // I get the QR text from the symbol
if(d.startsWith(QRUri)) { // QRUri is a string const containig the prefix
    int id;
    try {
        Log.d("NOT", "QR Subst \"" + d.substring(QRUri.length()) + "\""); // Print the data after the Prefix
        id = Integer.parseInt(d.substring(QRUri.length())); // Try to parse it to int
    } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        id = 0;
    }
}
```

This code worked for every QR so far, but today I found that for "SpecificPrefix/76" it didn't.

This is the log:

```
D/NOT﹕ QR Subst "﻿76"
D/NOT﹕ No Int found!
W/System.err﹕ java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "﻿76"
W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:375)
W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:366)
W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:332)
W/System.err﹕ at [...].MainActivity$3.onPreviewFrame(MainActivity.java:146)
W/System.err﹕ at android.hardware.Camera$EventHandler.handleMessage(Camera.java:841)
W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "﻿76"**
I can't get why it doesn't work!

Tested on Android 4.1.2 but it seems not to work on 4.4.2 either.

Thanks in advance to anyone hoping to work it out.

Comment: at a guess, I would bet you have invisible characters in your string. Check this post out, and maybe try it on that specific string. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6198986/how-can-i-replace-non-printable-unicode-characters-in-java

Comment: Did you try to trim the with `id = Integer.parseInt(d.substring(QRUri.length()).trim());`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After copying the entire string into Eclipse to test this, I can duplicate this issue.  I opened the source code in "binary mode" in TextPad to see if there were some strange characters in the string, and sure enough, there are.

```
22 EF BB BF 37 36 22     "???76"
```

I googled the string "EFBBBF" and found out that sequence of bytes is [the Unicode "byte order mark"](http://www.herongyang.com/Unicode/Notepad-Byte-Order-Mark-BOM-FEFF-EFBBBF.html).

> When this BOM character, U+FEFF, is serialized in UTF-8 encoding, it becomes an octet sequence of EF BB BF (\xEFBBBF).

Sure enough, I hit delete when my cursor was in between the first double-quote and the 7, and no characters disappeared.  (A second delete removed the double-quote, so I put it back.)  After that, `Integer.parseInt` was able to find the integer `76`.

You'll need to adjust your program to account for this character if it's appearing in your strings.

Comment: Thank you, the first thing I tried was to trim the string, but those chars are not whitespaces. The error was on the QR: I built the QR with a py script from a CSV file and the first row was the one with 76!