# AssertEquals(String, String) ComparisonFailure when contents are identical

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit4

I'm facing the following scenario:

I have an app that spits everything out to the STDOUT (simple company test) and I'm trying to JUnit this.

My problem is, when I run the application, it returns me in the Console:
(copy and pasted from IntelliJ)

```
Id 1234 nao encontrado
123, R$ 441,00
321, R$ -8490,00
255, R$ 884,00
```

Print:

[image]

And my test is:

```
assertEquals(outContent.toString().trim(),"Id 1234 nao encontrado\n" +
                "123, R$ 441,00\n" +
                "321, R$ -8490,00\n" +
                "255, R$ 884,00");
```

I'm getting:

```
junit.framework.ComparisonFailure:  <Click to see difference>


    at junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:100)
    at junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:107)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.assertEquals(TestCase.java:269)
    at com.company.AccountManagerTest.testPrintAccountsBalance(AccountManagerTest.java:85)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:176)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:141)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:122)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:142)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:125)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:129)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:252)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:247)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:86)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

[image]

So, what I am doing wrong here ?

Testing with JUnit4 and assertJ 2.4.0

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The visible characters are identical, but the non-printable characters are not.

You are comparing expected output containing CRLF (`\r\n`) to actual output with just LF (`\n`). You can see that in IntelliJ above the right-hand side of both text areas.

Simple solution is to replace the `\n`'s in your string with `\r\n`. Or remove `\r` from the other.

---

It is also worth noting that the parameter ordering is actually `(Object expected, Object actual)`, so the `outContent` should go second since that is the "actual" output.

Comment: If you're not sure whether the string will have `\r` or not, another solution is to use `outContent.toString().trim().replace("\r","")` as the actual string.  That is, remove all the `\r` characters before comparing.

Comment: Any way to debug this except by looking at it by hand?

Comment: There are 31 non printable characters, so I would say that if you really don't care about them, then just strip them all out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6198986/how-can-i-replace-non-printable-unicode-characters-in-java

Answer (score 11):

You can use AssertJ "isEqualToNormalizingNewline" as in:

```
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

...

@Test
public void ingoreLineEndingCharacterTest() {
    assertThat("First Line\nSecond Line\n").isEqualToNormalizingNewlines("First Line\r\nSecond Line\r\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The real issue is with System configuration of "line separator", not with unit test or input / output. Likely code is run on Windows platform which has default line separator as CRLF or `\r\n`. Unix or Mac, however, have default line separator as LF or `\n`.

Simplest way to fix this could be setting default line separator in the IDE. For example, IntelliJ provides elegant way of fixing this IDE or Project wide, or for a file. See [IntelliJ : Configuring Line Separators﻿](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-line-endings-and-line-separators.html).

**IDE / Project wide**

> [image]

**File**

> [image]

Answer (score 1):

Using JUnit and Assertj, you can compare strings ignoring the line separator (`\r, \n, \r\n`)

```
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

...

assertThat(resultString).isEqualToIgnoringWhitespace(expectedString);
```