# NumberFormatException while parsing an int

Tags: java, string, int

So I am making file reader/writer that can access a given file and save/read from it.I am having a problem while reading from the file. The contents are integers, string and double separated by "|" delimiters. I am using StringTokenizer to separate the tokens and save them to each individual variable but when I am reading the integers I get a NumberFormatException even though the string contains only an int.

Here is the code:

```
FileReader fr = new FileReader(filename);
BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(fr);
String line;

while ((line = buff.readLine()) != null) {
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line, "|");
    while (st.hasMoreElements()) {
         int Id = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
         String Name = st.nextToken();
         double cordX = Double.parseDouble(st.nextToken());
         double cordY = Double.parseDouble(st.nextToken());
    }
}
```

An example line of the file :

```
8502113|Aarau|47.391355|8.051251
```

And the error :

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "8502113"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
at storage.FileUtilities.readCitiesFromFile(FileUtilities.java:63)
at basics.Test.main(Test.java:16)
```

Am I missing something here? Is StringTokenizer tampering the string in some kind of way that I don't know?

EDIT: Here is the code that creates the file:

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(filename, !overwrite); // For FileWriter true = append, false = overwrite, so we flip the value.
    BufferedWriter buff = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    String coordConvertor;

    for (int i = 0; i <= cities.size() - 1; i++) {
        buff.write(Integer.toString(cities.get(i).getId()));
        buff.write("|");
        buff.write(cities.get(i).getName());
        buff.write("|");
        coordConvertor = Double.toString(cities.get(i).getCoord().getX());
        buff.write(coordConvertor);
        buff.write("|");
        coordConvertor = Double.toString(cities.get(i).getCoord().getY());
        buff.write(coordConvertor);
        buff.newLine();
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. Maybe your file contains some invisible characters (like BOM mark usually placed at start of file). Read that part as string and instead of parsing it print its `length()` to see if number of character matches what you see.

Comment: "8502113" contain `U+FEFF` Unicode Character

Comment: @Pshemo Indeed you are correct. The length appears to be +1. How can I resolve this? Is there a way to trim the extra character at the start of the file? EDIT: The file is a standard .txt file

Comment: Usually solution is to not put that mark in the file in the first place. How are you creating that file?

Comment: FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(filename, !overwrite); Just this line

Comment: @YassinHajaj if you copy "8502113" from above error and assign it to a int you can reproduce it.example http://ideone.com/y3vy2T

Comment: `FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(filename, !overwrite);` shouldn't be able to add that BOM (byte order mark) by itself. Then it should come from input which you are storing later in that file.

Comment: I updated the question to include the code for making and writing to the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are **hidden unicode characters** in the **String** your retrieved with **st.nextToken()**.
Use this code instead to remove them

```
int Id = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken().replaceAll("\\p{C}", ""));
String Name = st.nextToken().replaceAll("\\p{C}", "");
double cordX = Double.parseDouble(st.nextToken().replaceAll("\\p{C}", ""));
double cordY = Double.parseDouble(st.nextToken().replaceAll("\\p{C}", ""));
```

Comment: This seems to have fixed the problem but I don't understand where do these unicode characters come from? Also can you explain what expression in replaceAll does exactly?

Comment: I just took that solution from [How can I replace non-printable Unicode characters in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6198986/how-can-i-replace-non-printable-unicode-characters-in-java)