# How to remove \u200B (Zero Length Whitespace Unicode Character) from String in Java?

Tags: java, regex, string, unicode, outlook

My application is using **Spring Integration** for email polling from **Outlook** mailbox.

As, it is receiving the String (**email body**)from an external system (Outlook), So I have **no** control over it.

For Example,

```
String emailBodyStr= "rejected by sundar14-\u200B.";
```

Now I am trying to **remove** the unicode character **\u200B** from this String.

**What I tried already.**

**Try#1:**

```
emailBodyStr = emailBodyStr.replaceAll("\u200B", "");
```

**Try#2:**

```
`emailBodyStr = emailBodyStr.replaceAll("\u200B", "").trim();`
```

**Try#3** (using **Apache** Commons):

```
StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(emailBodyStr);
```

**Try#4:**

```
StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(emailBodyStr).trim();
```

**Nothing worked** till now.

When I tried to **print** this String using below code.

```
logger.info("Comment BEFORE:{}",emailBodyStr);
logger.info("Comment AFTER :{}",emailBodyStr);
```

In **Eclipse** console, it is **NOT** printing unicode char,

> Comment BEFORE:rejected by sundar14-​.

But the same code prints the unicode char in **Linux console** as below.

> Comment BEFORE:rejected by sundar14-\u200B.

I read some examples where **str.replace()** is recommended, but please note that examples uses **javascript, PHP** and **not** Java.

Comment: The `replaceAll` approach works when I try it.

Comment: how you tested it? able to print?

Comment: Before trying to replace it, I see an unprintable character in the output (shows up as "?"), and the length is 23. After replacing it, the unprintable character is gone and the length is 22.

Comment: Where are you seeing "?", in your IDE console? Which IDE you are using?  When I used str.replaceAll(), I was also getting count 23 (before) and 22 (after), but When I stored this string (after str.replaceAll()) in database - I can see '\u200B' in DB.

Comment: I see the question mark when running in Windows command prompt. Also, comparing the `String` with another one created without the \u200B shows that they're equal.

Comment: Simple replace works - http://ideone.com/MPGzqA

Comment: Big props figuring out your own answer! Fyi though, I believe the reason you originally had this problem is that you used `replaceAll()` instead of `replace()`. `replaceAll()` treats its first argument as a regex string, and since your input of `\u200B` has a \, it parses incorrectly and doesn't replace as it can't find the search string.

Comment: Excellent job writing this question! Very thorough.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Finally,** I am able to remove '[Zero Width Space](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200B/index.htm)' character by using '[Unicode Regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html)'.

```
String plainEmailBody = new String();
plainEmailBody = emailBodyStr.replaceAll("[\\p{Cf}]", "");
```

Reference to find the category of Unicode characters.

1. Character class from **Java**.

[Character](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) class from Java lists all of these unicode categories.

[image]

2. **Website:** http://www.fileformat.info/

[image: Character category]

3. **Website:** http://www.regular-expressions.info/  => Unicode Regular Expressions

[image: Unicode Regex for \u200B character]

**Note 1:** As I received this string from **Outlook Email Body** - **none** of the approaches listed in my question was working.

> My application is receiving a String from an external system
>   (**Outlook**), So I have no control over it.

**Note 2:** This SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6199346/1401019) helped me to know about **Unicode Regular Expressions** .