# How to remove end of cell special characters from a word document in java regex

Tags: java, regex

I am extracting data from tables within a Microsoft word document (.doc).

The data extracts fine but at the end of each extracted value (from each cell) there is a non-printable ^G character which is seriously messing with further processing.  I can only see this when I paste the console output into my text editor (TextMate).

What's the best way to remove this using regex. Is this a unicode character? I cant find any reference to ^G non printable characters. I assume its an end of cell character. To be honest I would rather get rid of all non-printable characters but at the moment this is the only one that is causing my any problems so either solution will do.

Comment: You can use: `input = input.replaceAll("\\P{Print}", "");` in Java to remove all non-printable characters.

Comment: `7 07 Alt-7 Ctrl-G ^G` - source ascii table

Comment: See [How can I replace non-printable Unicode characters in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6198986/how-can-i-replace-non-printable-unicode-characters-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To be honest I would rather get rid of all non-printable characters

You may use:

```
input = input.replaceAll("\\P{Print}", "");
```

in Java to remove all non-printable characters.

[`\p{Print}` matches all printable characters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) (including Unicode ones) and `\P{Print}` does the reverse by matching all non-printable characters.