# Invalid int when converting from string to integer

Tags: java, parsing

I'm trying to convert a string that contains just numbers to integer using `int number = Integer.parseInt(string)`, but it returns #

```
error: Invalid int: "number"
```

For example, if the string is "10", it returns: `Invalid int: "10"`. What is wrong?

**Edit:**

```
FileInputStream fis;
        int number =0;
        String line="";
        try
        {
            fis = new FileInputStream(getFilesDir()+pathToFile);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
            line=reader.readLine();
            Log.e("Read Line", "Read line: *" +line+ "*"); //returns *10*
            try
            {
                number = Integer.parseInt(line.trim());
            }
            catch(NumberFormatException nfe)
            {
                Log.e("ERROR CONVERTING", nfe.getMessage()); // return above error
            }
            reader.close();

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Log.e("ERROR OPENING FILE", "Can't open file: "+ex.getMessage());
        }
```

Comment: *might* be white space around string. try `Integer.parseInt(string.trim());`

Comment: Are you sure it's "ten" but not "one o"? I mean, check if zero is a zero, not caps o

Comment: I suspect the string isn't *just* `"10"`. Try logging its length as well - there may be some non-printable characters.

Comment: Also, "l" (lower case L) looks similar to "1" (one)

Comment: If you post the whole exact error we can help way better.

Comment: I think you giving input String string = "10  ";

Comment: Post the **exact** code and error, too much guessing around here.

Comment: I've tried Integer.parseInt(string.trim()); returns the same error. The string IS "10", no extra characters, I've logged it.

Comment: I've updated the question with code.

Answer (score 4):

I used the code in the answer from this question: [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4030928/extract-digits-from-a-string-in-java)

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\D+","");
```

Don't know why it doesn't work without this, because there are no other characters besides numbers in the string, but not it works.

Answer (score 2):

**Some times it means "the number is too big".**

I come across a situation where it happens because my number was too big.
Example:

```
Integer.parseInt("201506121234567");
```

It causes me the exception NumberFormat.

To solve, I changed to this:

```
Long.parseLong("201506121234567");
```

Hope it helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

Did you actually try with `"10"` or any other number? The error is pretty specific.

> Invalid int: "number"

This means that in this line

```
Integer.parseInt(string)
```

`string` has the value `"number"`. Check where are you setting this value and verify that you're actually setting a numeric string.

Comment: From OP: *if the string is "10", it returns: Invalid int: "10"*

Comment: @m0skit0 Actually, the OP started that sentence with _For example_. I'm not too sure he actually tried that.

Comment: Then I'd use a regex to actually depure the string and find the numeric characters on it.