# How to filter/extract data from String?

Tags: java

How to apply filter here

```
 String x=Showing 138 of 138 String(s)
```

i want to get only 138, ending value how to get that?

Comment: use regex to match the pattern

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4030928/extract-digits-from-a-string-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String x="Showing 158 of 138 String(s)";
    System.out.println(x.replaceAll(".*\\s(\\d+).*", "$1"));
}
```

O/P : `138`

Answer (score 0):

I would not use regex for this as it won't be flexible solution. Try Paring the string to get valid value:

```
String s =" String x=Showing 138 of 138 String(s)";
String[] words = s.split(" ");
BigDecimal value = null;
for(String word : words) {
    try {
        value = BigDecimal.valueOf(word);
        } catch(NumberFormatException e) {}
    }
System.out.println(value);
```

Comment: `s.split(" ");` ==> You are using regex :)

Comment: @TheLostMind Close enough, but not one that would fail to detect doubles ;)

Comment: Well, the OP didn't say that he wanted decimals.