# Remove all non numeric value from textView

Tags: android, textview, autocompletetextview

After test it on my application, I get numeric value(phone) and string values(names)  in TextView field. I want remove all non numeric values.

```
  public class SendingSMSActivity extends Activity{
private int mCount;
private AutoCompleteTextView actv;
private ArrayList<String> mcurrentssFistLastName_PhoneList = null;
AutoCompleteTextView PhoneNumberAutoComp;
MultiAutoCompleteTextView PhoneNumberMultiAutoComp;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sending_sms_activity);
    PhoneNumberAutoComp=(AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.aCT_phone_number);
    PhoneNumberMultiAutoComp=(MultiAutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.multiCompTextView);

    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,init());

    PhoneNumberAutoComp.setAdapter(adapter);
    PhoneNumberAutoComp.setThreshold(1);

    PhoneNumberMultiAutoComp.setAdapter(adapter);
    PhoneNumberMultiAutoComp.setTokenizer(new MultiAutoCompleteTextView.CommaTokenizer());
}

private ArrayList<String> init(){
    mcurrentssFistLastName_PhoneList = new ArrayList<String>();
    //mcurrentssFistLastNameList = new ArrayList<String>();
    InnerDB db = new InnerDB(SendingSMSActivity.this);

    final ArrayList<String> sPhoneList = db.getAllPhoneNumber();
    final ArrayList<String> sFirstLastNameList = db.getAllSFirstName();
    mCount = sPhoneList.size();
    for(int i = 0; i < mCount; i ++){
        mcurrentssFistLastName_PhoneList.add(sFirstLastNameList.get(i) +" " +sPhoneList.get(i));
        //mcurrentssFistLastNameList.add(sFirstLastNameList.get(i));
    }

    return mcurrentssFistLastName_PhoneList;
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}
}
```

Comment: Post your xml please

Comment: You can always replace it with replaceAll("[^0-9]",""); .This will return you only numeric values

Comment: Many thanks @PrateekRathore :                 String phonevalue =  PhoneNumberAutoComp.getText().toString();
                String phoneNum =phonevalue.replaceAll("[^0-9]","");
                PhoneNumberAutoComp.setText(phoneNum);

Comment: Bro, mark my correct, LOL

Comment: Sure bro, I did it

Comment: It is very simple check it. <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4030928/extract-digits-from-a-string-in-java>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always replace it with replaceAll("[^0-9]",""); .This will return you only numeric values .

Answer (score 1):

With the feedback of @PrateekRathore I got the solution:

```
String phonevalue =  PhoneNumberAutoComp.getText().toString();
            String phoneNum =phonevalue.replaceAll("[^0-9]","");
            PhoneNumberAutoComp.setText(phoneNum);
```