# ParseInt keeps getting a zero

Tags: java

I am reading a text file in from another program that is this(I really just am trying to save the first number of each line. I am simulating a memory and CPU interaction so these are codes in another class:

```
1    // Load 0
0
14   // CopyToX
4    // LoadIdxX 32 (load from A-Z table) 
32
21   // JumpIfEqual 12 
12
9    // Put 2 (output as char)
2
25   // IncX
20   // Jump 3
3
1    // Load 0
0
16   // CopyToY
5    // LoadIdxY 59 (load from 1-10 table)
59
21   // JumpIfEqual 27
27
9    // Put 1 (output as int)
1
1    // Load 1  (because no IncY instruction)
1
11   // AddY
16   // CopyToY
20   // Jump 15
15
1    // Print newline
10
9
2
50   // End
65   // Data A-Z
66
67
68
69
70
71
72
73
74
75
76
77
78
79
80
81
82
83
84
85
86
87
88
89
90
0
1    // Data 1-10
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
0

.1000
30
```

I am trying to just save it into the memory array, but while debugging it I see that the value stored is zero. I cant figure it out! I added the "[0]" because the compiler would throw this error without it

`The method parseInt(String) in the type Integer is not applicable for the arguments (String[])`

So, any help is much appreciated here is the block of code!

```
String line;
int init=0;
while((line= Fileread.readLine())!=null)
    {
System.out.println(line.length());
    if(line.length()==0)
        break;
    try
    {
        memory[init++]=Integer.parseInt(line.trim().split(" ")[0]);
        System.out.println(memory[init]);
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException e)
    {
        init=Integer.parseInt(line.substring(1));
    }
}
```

Comment: show the actual format of text file. or  does your text file contain one number per line because the accurate solution depend on the file format

Comment: Okay I included the whole text file @PavneetSingh

Comment: as you can see you also have slashes ans string with it , you just want the numbers i gues

Comment: As @PavneetSingh mentioned, you need to extract only number from your string. Check this post to extract number from string: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4030928/extract-digits-from-a-string-in-java

Comment: Also you are breaking the loop after encountering first empty string which will essentially read only first line of your file. Do you really need that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're incrementing `init` before you actually print the value.
So your code is printing `0` because you haven't assigned anything to `memory[init]` yet.

```
String line;
int init=0;
while((line= Fileread.readLine())!=null)
    {
System.out.println(line.length());
    if(line.length()==0)
        break;
    try
    {
        memory[init]=Integer.parseInt(line.trim().split(" ")[0]);
        System.out.println(memory[init]);
        init++;
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException e)
    {
        init=Integer.parseInt(line.substring(1));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code could be something like this:

```
String line;
int init=0;
while((line= Fileread.readLine())!=null)
    {
System.out.println(line.length());
    if(line.length()==0)
        break;
    String num= str.replaceAll("\\D+","");

    try
    {
       if(num.length() == 0){
        memory[init++]=Integer.parseInt(num);
        System.out.println(memory[init]);
       }
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException e)
    {
        init=Integer.parseInt(line.substring(1));
    }
}
```