# How to remove decimal in java without removing the remaining digits

Tags: java

Is there any method to remove the `.` in java into a `double` value?

Example :

```
56.11124
```

to

```
5611124
```

Comment: converting to string and replace the dot?

Comment: Duplicate e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4030928/extract-digits-from-a-string-in-java

Comment: @Jodn That question is not a duplicate, although its related.

Comment: What should the result be a string?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract digits from a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4030928/extract-digits-from-a-string-in-java)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there's a mathematical way to find out how many decimals there are in a double. You can convert to a `String`, replace the dot, and then convert it back:

```
Double.parseDouble(Double.toString(56.11124).replace(".", ""));
```

Be careful of overflows when you parse the result though!

Comment: Can anyone explain the downvotes? If you have a better solution, please share it.

Comment: @Jens and so ?^^ that's what asks the user ^^ remove the point makes the double become another

Comment: That is true @ScaryWombat. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

This might work

```
class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double val = 56.1112;
        while( (double)((int)val) != val )
        {
            val *= 10;
        }

        System.out.printf( "%.0f", val );
    }
}
```

**Output:** `561112`

This works by casting the double to int which truncates the floating information `56.11124 => 56`. While the values aren't equal you multiply it by the base to push the `.` out. I don't know if this is the best way.

Comment: this outputs `56` but the OP wants `5611124` so this is no helping answer at all...

Comment: @Lino at what point does the above code snippet print out 56? I went ahead and made a full working example in case it's not obvious.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert to `BigDecimal` and use the `unscaledValue` method:

```
BigInteger unscaled = new BigDecimal(myDouble).unscaledValue();
```

Depending on your intended output, you might also use `BigDecimal#valueof(double)` to create the intermediate `BigDecimal`.

[Javadoc for BigDecimal#new(double)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal(double))

[Javadoc for BigDecimal#valueOf(double)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#valueOf(double))

[Javadoc for BigDecimal#unscaledValue()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#unscaledValue())

Comment: Be careful when using the double constructor of big decimal as the javadoc states it can be unpredictable...

Comment: That's true but only when using literal values (`new BigDecimal(0.1)`). If using with a preexisting variable it should work (`new BigDecimal(myDouble)`)

Comment: it doesn't ;) try following snippet, it prints true. `double d = 0.1;
        BigDecimal bigDecimal = new BigDecimal(d);
        System.out.println(bigDecimal.doubleValue() == 0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625);`

Comment: `System.out.println(0.1 == 0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625);` also prints true... The difference has to do with the usage of [Double.toString](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#toString(double)), which uses "at least one digit to represent the fractional part, and beyond that as many, but only as many, more digits as are needed to uniquely distinguish the argument value from adjacent values of type double.". What this means is that it prints "prettier" versions of values.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it,

First, convert the double to a string. Then, call `replace` to replace `.` with an empty string. After that, parse the result into an int:

```
double d = 5.1;
String doubleString = Double.toString(5.1);
String removedDot = doubleString.replace(".", "");
int result = Integer.parseInt(removedDot);
```

Obviously, this wouldn't work if the double's string representation is in scientific notation like `5e16`. This also does not work on integral double values, like `5`, as its string representation is `5.0`.

`double`s are inaccurate by nature. `5` and `5.0` are the same value. This is why you can't really do this kind of operation. Do you expect different results for `a` and `b`?

```
double a = 5;
double b = 5.0;
```

If you do, then you can't really do this, since there is no way of knowing what the programmer wrote exactly at runtime.

Comment: be vary that scientific notation just converts to a value behind the scences. `5e3` is equal to `5000`. So your answer works fine even for scientific notation

Comment: @Lino No, for larger numbers, `toString` makes it into scientific notation.

Answer (score -1):

You can convert it to a `String` and remove the `.` and convert it back to `double` something like

```
double value = 56.11124;
value = Double.valueOf(("" + value).replace(".", "")).doubleValue();
```

This will return 5611124.0 since its a double you will have the floating point. You can convert it to an `int`, but you have to take care of the possible overflow. Otherwise it would look like this

```
int normalized = (int) value;
```