# date time parse is not enforcing the format

Tags: java, scala, datetime

I have a string and a format. I want to convert the string to date time using the format. But simple date time format is converting the string to date time even the input string is in a wrong format.

```
val formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd")
val dateInString = "2017042er7"

try {
formatter.setLenient(false)
val date = formatter.parse(dateInString)
System.out.println(date)
System.out.println(formatter.format(date));

} catch  {

 case e:Exception=>println(e)
}
```

How can I enforce the format?

**UPDATE:: ** using joda time formatter solved the issue. You can also use java time formatter(as one of the answers suggested).

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleTextFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Likewise, the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the java.time classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the new `java.time` API and its `DateTimeFormatter` to parse your dates.  it allows for much greater control and correctness and is stricter with the format.

Leave the old `java.util.Date`, and `SimpleDateFormatter` behind and just convert to them when you need it to interact with a library.

Comment: @Luniam yes, but you should actually drop jodatime in favor of the new java.time as well as java.time is the successor to jodatime post java 8.

Answer (score 0):

`setLenient` doesn't care so much about the String format, rather that the value passed can be converted into a date.  For example, should `31-Sept-2017` be treated as `01-Aug-2017`.

The library is trying to be helpful by parsing your input (dd is a number, so 2 fulfils that requirement, everything after that can be ignored).  If you require the `String` format to be exact, then you should use a regular expression to validate the input before converting it.

BTW, I'm not necessarily agreeing with the implementation, just trying to explain why it works :)

Comment: It should not parse exactly as the format. Otherwise, what's the point of providing the format. I am getting a wrong value while I was expecting something else. I would say it is a bad implementation. Joda time is better. Using joda time solved the issue I was having.

Comment: I don't disagree, just explaining why you're seeing the results you are.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.parse(                              // Use modern java.time classes.
    "2017042er7".replaceAll( "\\D+" , "" ) ,  // Extract digits from string.
    DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE          // Use pre-defined formatter for YYYYMMDD input, the “basic” version of standard ISO 8601 format.
).toString()                                  // Generate String in full version of ISO 8601 format (with hyphens as separators).
```

> 2017-04-27

## Extract digits

As explained in [*Extract digits from a string in Java*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4030928/642706), extract the digits only from the string.

```
String original = "2017042er7" ;
String input = original.replaceAll( "\\D+" , "" ) ;
```

## Parse as `LocalDate`

Avoid the troublesome old legacy date-time classes seen in the Question. Supplanted by java.time classes.

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

The [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class contains a pre-defined formatting pattern to fit your needs: [BASIC_ISO_DATE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#BASIC_ISO_DATE). That is the “basic” version (minimizing use of separators) of the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( input , DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE ) ;
```

See this [code run live in IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/OIHiOH).

> original: 2017042er7
>
> ld.toString(): 2017-04-27