# How to extract the sub-string "2882649" from the string "automation130214141113 (order # 2882649)" using Java

Tags: java, regex, delimiter

I am trying to extract only **2882649** from a string **automation130214141113 (order # 2882649)**.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract digits from a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4030928/extract-digits-from-a-string-in-java)

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you want a more dynamic solution for this, more context would help.  But the following will parse the string down to just "2882649" as a string:

```
String str = "automation130214141113 (order # 2882649)";
String[] splitStr = str.split(" ");
String result = splitStr[3].substring(0, splitStr[3].length() - 1);
```

This is not the most elegant way to do this but you'll notice if you print result it will be the string "2882649".

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO. Here is the simple approach.

```
String rawText = "automation130214141113 (order # 2882649)";
String number = rawText.substring(s.indexOf("# ") + 1).substring(0, s.indexOf(")"));
System.out.println(number);
```

Answer (score 0):

To extract the *sub-string* **2882649** from the *string* **automation130214141113 (order # 2882649)** the easiest way would be to use *multiple delimiters* the **`#`** and the **`)`** character and you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  String MyString = "automation130214141113 (order # 2882649)";
  String[] SplitString = MyString.split("# |\\)");
  System.out.println(SplitString[1]);
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  2882649
  ```