# What are the options in java to split string and remove not needed chars?

Tags: java, string, replace, split

I have to pars strings as one below:

```java
String input = "{\"1\",\"2\",\"3\"}";
```

As an output I want to have an array of string with only numbers, something like that:

```java
String[] output = new String[]{"1","2","3"};
```

My current working solution is:

```java
String[] output = input.replaceAll("\\{|\\}|\"", "").split(",");
```

Are there any other solution that could do the same?
More readable or relevant?

Comment: This would be better posted on a code review page

Comment: Depends on the degree of freedom of the input. Is ,, ok ? For your example ( and some variations) it seems ok.

Comment: ,, - should not occur.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract digits from a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4030928/extract-digits-from-a-string-in-java)

Comment: Your input String seems strange to me. It looks like JSON but this is for sure not a valid JSON object. Would you have any way of changing the source of the String so it would be a valid JSON array as `"[\"1\",\"2\",\"3\"]"`

Comment: It is a string from DB, result of ARRAY_AGG function.

Answer (score 1):

You could fetch all numbers instead of removing all special chars:

```
String input = "{\"1\",\"2\",\"3\"}";

List<String> matches = new ArrayList<>();

Matcher numberMatcher = Pattern.compile("\\d+").matcher(input);
while (numberMatcher.find()) {
  matches.add(numberMatcher.group());
}
```

Using

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `x.replaceAll("\\D+", " ")` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4030936/6436977) which @Emre Acar suggested instead of your own regex  might improve readability a bit. 
Other than that using `split(",")` is probably already the most readable way to do it.

I highly doubt that this is more readable than your solution, but if you want to do it in a "relevant" fancy way you *could* use streams:

```
    String input = "{\"1\",\"2\",\"3\"}";
    String[] output = Stream.of(input)
            .map(x -> x.replaceAll("\\D+", " "))
            .toArray(String[]::new);
    System.out.println("output: " + Arrays.toString(output));
    // output: [ 1 2 3 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is the simplest. Just for fun, here is a solution that also verifies that the input string is syntactically correct:

```
private static final Pattern OUTER = Pattern.compile("\\{(.*)\\}");
private static final Pattern INNER = Pattern.compile("\\\"(\\d+)\\\"(?:,(.*))?");

...

    String input = "{\"1\",\"2\",\"3\"}";
    Matcher matcher = OUTER.matcher(input);
    if (!matcher.matches()) {
        // Syntax error
    } else {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        input = matcher.group(1);
        while (input != null) {
            matcher = INNER.matcher(input);
            if (!matcher.matches()) {
                // Syntax error
            } else {
                list.add(matcher.group(1));
                input = matcher.group(2);
            }
        }
        String[] output = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try input.replaceAll(",", "").substring(1, input.length - 1).split("\"")

First you remove the commas from the string by replacing them with empty strings, then you remove the brackets by leaving out the first and the last character and finally you split at the escaped apostrophes (though this might end you up with empty entries in your finaly Array, so you need to catch these. I will think about a sloution that doesn't do that).