# PhoneNumberUtils Change Number Format

Tags: android, android-studio, phonenumberutils

I am PhoneNumberUtil to see phone numbers i enter into a text view and then send them a message. However it does not work as my Numbers are Formated with a '+44 ...' whereas PhoneNumberUtils needs numbers to be written like '44...'. Does anyone know how i can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding your issue correctly, it sounds like you want to [strip just the numbers from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4030928/extract-digits-from-a-string-in-java) to leave an unformatted number for the formatter to work with.